# Не понимаю в чём ошибка при попытке ставить данные в таблицу mysql

Tags: mysql

Команда:

```
INSERT INTO filmStage (index, stageContent) VALUES (4, 'Chaitali');
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, stageContent) VALUES (4, 'Chaitali')' at line 1
```

Версия MySQL: `8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2`

Comment: [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете зарезервированное в mysql слово "index" в запросе. Попробуйте обернуть его в кавычки:

```
INSERT INTO filmStage (`index`, `stageContent`) VALUES (4, 'Chaitali');
```

Если это не поможет, то предлагаю вам переименовать "index" на что нибудь другое.

Comment: Переименовать - это более правильно, и этот совет скорее надо поставить первым.